# Indy 9.0.50 openssl dlls

Tags: c++, dll, ssl, c++builder, indy

I've look all over and can't seem to find a version of the openssl dll for indy 9.0.50

found a few versions but none of them work

i get either failed to load of failed to setcipher

can some one point me in the right direction?

Comment: I guess you should look for whichever version of OpenSSL was current when 9.0.50 was built. Do you know what that was / when that was? Is it really not in the documentation? Could you update to the latest version of Indy?

Comment: not sure when it was. but i think i am looking for something like 0.97. cant update to indy 10 as we have to much using indy9 and would need to update alot of code

Comment: The oldest versions of Indy specific OpenSSL DLLs I can find are:  0.9.6, 0.9.6b, 0.9.6k, 0.9.6m, http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/Archive/

Comment: And, what happpened when you tried them?  If you want help, you need to provide more information.  What EXACT versions did you try?  What EXACT error messages are you getting?  What does Indy's `WhichFailedtoLoad()` function return?

Comment: @Remy OpenSSL links imports by ordinal. I doubt you'd get useful errors if you tried to run against the wrong one - probably the wrong number of caller-cleaned arguments at the end of some function call corrupting the stack.

Comment: OpenSSL does not link imports by ordinal. Certainly not any of the versions that Indy has ever used.  Indy has always relied on OpenSSL exporting its functions by name. Indy has always dynamically loaded the OpenSSL DLLs at runtime via `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()`. It has never statically linked to them at compile-time.  `WhichFailedToLoad()` reports which DLLs and/or functions were not found at run-time.

Comment: i get the following errors wiith teh following versions

Answer (score -1):

I get the following errors with the following versions

Version 096 Failed to load ssl Library.'.
SSL Error:
 EVP_md5 X509_STORE_CTX_get_error X509_STORE_CTX_set_error X509_STORE_CTX_get_error_depth X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert X509_digest X509_NAME_oneline X509_set_issuer_name X509_get_issuer_name X509_set_subject_name X509_get_subject_name X509_NAME_hash SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list SSL_CTX_new SSL_CTX_free SSL_set_fd SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file SSL_load_error_strings SSL_state_string_long SSL_get_peer_certificate SSL_CTX_set_verify SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb_userdata SSL_CTX_check_private_key SSL_new SSL_free SSL_accept SSL_connect SSL_read SSL_peek SSL_write SSL_get_error SSLv2_method SSLv2_server_method SSLv2_client_method SSLv3_method SSLv3_server_method SSLv3_client_method SSLv23_method SSLv23_server_method SSLv23_client_method TLSv1_method TLSv1_server_method TLSv1_client_method SSL_shutdown SSL_set_connect_state SSL_set_accept_state SSL_set_shutdown SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations SSL_get_session SSL_library_init SSL_CTX_set_info_callback_indy X509_STORE_CTX_get_app_data_indy X509_get_notBefore_indy X509_get_notAfter_indy SSL_SESSION_get_id_indy SSL_SESSION_get_id_ctx_indy SSL_CTX_get_version_indy SSL_CTX_set_options_indy RAND_screen des_set_odd_parity des_set_key des_ecb_encrypt SSL_set_ex_data SSL_get_ex_data CRYPTO_num_locks CRYPTO_set_locking_callback CRYPTO_set_id_callback

Version 096b Failed to load ssl Library.'.
SSL Error:
 EVP_md5 X509_STORE_CTX_get_error X509_STORE_CTX_set_error X509_STORE_CTX_get_error_depth X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert X509_digest X509_NAME_oneline X509_set_issuer_name X509_get_issuer_name X509_set_subject_name X509_get_subject_name X509_NAME_hash SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list SSL_CTX_new SSL_CTX_free SSL_set_fd SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file SSL_load_error_strings SSL_state_string_long SSL_get_peer_certificate SSL_CTX_set_verify SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb_userdata SSL_CTX_check_private_key SSL_new SSL_free SSL_accept SSL_connect SSL_read SSL_peek SSL_write SSL_get_error SSLv2_method SSLv2_server_method SSLv2_client_method SSLv3_method SSLv3_server_method SSLv3_client_method SSLv23_method SSLv23_server_method SSLv23_client_method TLSv1_method TLSv1_server_method TLSv1_client_method SSL_shutdown SSL_set_connect_state SSL_set_accept_state SSL_set_shutdown SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations SSL_get_session SSL_library_init SSL_CTX_set_info_callback_indy X509_STORE_CTX_get_app_data_indy X509_get_notBefore_indy X509_get_notAfter_indy SSL_SESSION_get_id_indy SSL_SESSION_get_id_ctx_indy SSL_CTX_get_version_indy SSL_CTX_set_options_indy RAND_screen des_set_odd_parity des_set_key des_ecb_encrypt SSL_set_ex_data SSL_get_ex_data CRYPTO_num_locks CRYPTO_set_locking_callback CRYPTO_set_id_callback

Version 096k Failed to load ssl Library.'.
SSL Error:
 EVP_md5 X509_STORE_CTX_get_error X509_STORE_CTX_set_error X509_STORE_CTX_get_error_depth X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert X509_digest X509_NAME_oneline X509_set_issuer_name X509_get_issuer_name X509_set_subject_name X509_get_subject_name X509_NAME_hash SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list SSL_CTX_new SSL_CTX_free SSL_set_fd SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file SSL_load_error_strings SSL_state_string_long SSL_get_peer_certificate SSL_CTX_set_verify SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb_userdata SSL_CTX_check_private_key SSL_new SSL_free SSL_accept SSL_connect SSL_read SSL_peek SSL_write SSL_get_error SSLv2_method SSLv2_server_method SSLv2_client_method SSLv3_method SSLv3_server_method SSLv3_client_method SSLv23_method SSLv23_server_method SSLv23_client_method TLSv1_method TLSv1_server_method TLSv1_client_method SSL_shutdown SSL_set_connect_state SSL_set_accept_state SSL_set_shutdown SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations SSL_get_session SSL_library_init SSL_CTX_set_info_callback_indy X509_STORE_CTX_get_app_data_indy X509_get_notBefore_indy X509_get_notAfter_indy SSL_SESSION_get_id_indy SSL_SESSION_get_id_ctx_indy SSL_CTX_get_version_indy SSL_CTX_set_options_indy RAND_screen des_set_odd_parity des_set_key des_ecb_encrypt SSL_set_ex_data SSL_get_ex_data CRYPTO_num_locks CRYPTO_set_locking_callback CRYPTO_set_id_callback

Version 096m Failed to load ssl Library.'. 
SSL Error:
 EVP_md5 X509_STORE_CTX_get_error X509_STORE_CTX_set_error X509_STORE_CTX_get_error_depth X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert X509_digest X509_NAME_oneline X509_set_issuer_name X509_get_issuer_name X509_set_subject_name X509_get_subject_name X509_NAME_hash SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list SSL_CTX_new SSL_CTX_free SSL_set_fd SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file SSL_load_error_strings SSL_state_string_long SSL_get_peer_certificate SSL_CTX_set_verify SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb_userdata SSL_CTX_check_private_key SSL_new SSL_free SSL_accept SSL_connect SSL_read SSL_peek SSL_write SSL_get_error SSLv2_method SSLv2_server_method SSLv2_client_method SSLv3_method SSLv3_server_method SSLv3_client_method SSLv23_method SSLv23_server_method SSLv23_client_method TLSv1_method TLSv1_server_method TLSv1_client_method SSL_shutdown SSL_set_connect_state SSL_set_accept_state SSL_set_shutdown SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations SSL_get_session SSL_library_init SSL_CTX_set_info_callback_indy X509_STORE_CTX_get_app_data_indy X509_get_notBefore_indy X509_get_notAfter_indy SSL_SESSION_get_id_indy SSL_SESSION_get_id_ctx_indy SSL_CTX_get_version_indy SSL_CTX_set_options_indy RAND_screen des_set_odd_parity des_set_key des_ecb_encrypt SSL_set_ex_data SSL_get_ex_data CRYPTO_num_locks CRYPTO_set_locking_callback CRYPTO_set_id_callback

Version 098h Failed to load ssl Library.'. 
SSL Error:
 EVP_md5 X509_STORE_CTX_get_error X509_STORE_CTX_set_error X509_STORE_CTX_get_error_depth X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert X509_digest X509_NAME_oneline X509_set_issuer_name X509_get_issuer_name X509_set_subject_name X509_get_subject_name X509_NAME_hash SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list SSL_CTX_new SSL_CTX_free SSL_set_fd SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file SSL_load_error_strings SSL_state_string_long SSL_get_peer_certificate SSL_CTX_set_verify SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb_userdata SSL_CTX_check_private_key SSL_new SSL_free SSL_accept SSL_connect SSL_read SSL_peek SSL_write SSL_get_error SSLv2_method SSLv2_server_method SSLv2_client_method SSLv3_method SSLv3_server_method SSLv3_client_method SSLv23_method SSLv23_server_method SSLv23_client_method TLSv1_method TLSv1_server_method TLSv1_client_method SSL_shutdown SSL_set_connect_state SSL_set_accept_state SSL_set_shutdown SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations SSL_get_session SSL_library_init SSL_CTX_set_info_callback_indy X509_STORE_CTX_get_app_data_indy X509_get_notBefore_indy X509_get_notAfter_indy SSL_SESSION_get_id_indy SSL_SESSION_get_id_ctx_indy SSL_CTX_get_version_indy SSL_CTX_set_options_indy RAND_screen des_set_odd_parity des_set_key des_ecb_encrypt SSL_set_ex_data SSL_get_ex_data CRYPTO_num_locks CRYPTO_set_locking_callback CRYPTO_set_id_callback

Version 098m Failed to load ssl Library.'.
SSL Error:
 EVP_md5 X509_STORE_CTX_get_error X509_STORE_CTX_set_error X509_STORE_CTX_get_error_depth X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert X509_digest X509_NAME_oneline X509_set_issuer_name X509_get_issuer_name X509_set_subject_name X509_get_subject_name X509_NAME_hash SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list SSL_CTX_new SSL_CTX_free SSL_set_fd SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file SSL_load_error_strings SSL_state_string_long SSL_get_peer_certificate SSL_CTX_set_verify SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb_userdata SSL_CTX_check_private_key SSL_new SSL_free SSL_accept SSL_connect SSL_read SSL_peek SSL_write SSL_get_error SSLv2_method SSLv2_server_method SSLv2_client_method SSLv3_method SSLv3_server_method SSLv3_client_method SSLv23_method SSLv23_server_method SSLv23_client_method TLSv1_method TLSv1_server_method TLSv1_client_method SSL_shutdown SSL_set_connect_state SSL_set_accept_state SSL_set_shutdown SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations SSL_get_session SSL_library_init SSL_CTX_set_info_callback_indy X509_STORE_CTX_get_app_data_indy X509_get_notBefore_indy X509_get_notAfter_indy SSL_SESSION_get_id_indy SSL_SESSION_get_id_ctx_indy SSL_CTX_get_version_indy SSL_CTX_set_options_indy RAND_screen des_set_odd_parity des_set_key des_ecb_encrypt SSL_set_ex_data SSL_get_ex_data CRYPTO_num_locks CRYPTO_set_locking_callback CRYPTO_set_id_callback

Version 098o Failed to load ssl Library.'. 
SSL Error:
 EVP_md5 X509_STORE_CTX_get_error X509_STORE_CTX_set_error X509_STORE_CTX_get_error_depth X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert X509_digest X509_NAME_oneline X509_set_issuer_name X509_get_issuer_name X509_set_subject_name X509_get_subject_name X509_NAME_hash SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list SSL_CTX_new SSL_CTX_free SSL_set_fd SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file SSL_load_error_strings SSL_state_string_long SSL_get_peer_certificate SSL_CTX_set_verify SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb_userdata SSL_CTX_check_private_key SSL_new SSL_free SSL_accept SSL_connect SSL_read SSL_peek SSL_write SSL_get_error SSLv2_method SSLv2_server_method SSLv2_client_method SSLv3_method SSLv3_server_method SSLv3_client_method SSLv23_method SSLv23_server_method SSLv23_client_method TLSv1_method TLSv1_server_method TLSv1_client_method SSL_shutdown SSL_set_connect_state SSL_set_accept_state SSL_set_shutdown SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations SSL_get_session SSL_library_init SSL_CTX_set_info_callback_indy X509_STORE_CTX_get_app_data_indy X509_get_notBefore_indy X509_get_notAfter_indy SSL_SESSION_get_id_indy SSL_SESSION_get_id_ctx_indy SSL_CTX_get_version_indy SSL_CTX_set_options_indy RAND_screen des_set_odd_parity des_set_key des_ecb_encrypt SSL_set_ex_data SSL_get_ex_data CRYPTO_num_locks CRYPTO_set_locking_callback CRYPTO_set_id_callback

Version 098q Failed to load ssl Library.'. 
SSL Error:
 EVP_md5 X509_STORE_CTX_get_error X509_STORE_CTX_set_error X509_STORE_CTX_get_error_depth X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert X509_digest X509_NAME_oneline X509_set_issuer_name X509_get_issuer_name X509_set_subject_name X509_get_subject_name X509_NAME_hash SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list SSL_CTX_new SSL_CTX_free SSL_set_fd SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file SSL_load_error_strings SSL_state_string_long SSL_get_peer_certificate SSL_CTX_set_verify SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb_userdata SSL_CTX_check_private_key SSL_new SSL_free SSL_accept SSL_connect SSL_read SSL_peek SSL_write SSL_get_error SSLv2_method SSLv2_server_method SSLv2_client_method SSLv3_method SSLv3_server_method SSLv3_client_method SSLv23_method SSLv23_server_method SSLv23_client_method TLSv1_method TLSv1_server_method TLSv1_client_method SSL_shutdown SSL_set_connect_state SSL_set_accept_state SSL_set_shutdown SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations SSL_get_session SSL_library_init SSL_CTX_set_info_callback_indy X509_STORE_CTX_get_app_data_indy X509_get_notBefore_indy X509_get_notAfter_indy SSL_SESSION_get_id_indy SSL_SESSION_get_id_ctx_indy SSL_CTX_get_version_indy SSL_CTX_set_options_indy RAND_screen des_set_odd_parity des_set_key des_ecb_encrypt SSL_set_ex_data SSL_get_ex_data CRYPTO_num_locks CRYPTO_set_locking_callback CRYPTO_set_id_callback

Version 098r Failed to load ssl Library.'.
SSL Error:
 EVP_md5 X509_STORE_CTX_get_error X509_STORE_CTX_set_error X509_STORE_CTX_get_error_depth X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert X509_digest X509_NAME_oneline X509_set_issuer_name X509_get_issuer_name X509_set_subject_name X509_get_subject_name X509_NAME_hash SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list SSL_CTX_new SSL_CTX_free SSL_set_fd SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file SSL_load_error_strings SSL_state_string_long SSL_get_peer_certificate SSL_CTX_set_verify SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb_userdata SSL_CTX_check_private_key SSL_new SSL_free SSL_accept SSL_connect SSL_read SSL_peek SSL_write SSL_get_error SSLv2_method SSLv2_server_method SSLv2_client_method SSLv3_method SSLv3_server_method SSLv3_client_method SSLv23_method SSLv23_server_method SSLv23_client_method TLSv1_method TLSv1_server_method TLSv1_client_method SSL_shutdown SSL_set_connect_state SSL_set_accept_state SSL_set_shutdown SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations SSL_get_session SSL_library_init SSL_CTX_set_info_callback_indy X509_STORE_CTX_get_app_data_indy X509_get_notBefore_indy X509_get_notAfter_indy SSL_SESSION_get_id_indy SSL_SESSION_get_id_ctx_indy SSL_CTX_get_version_indy SSL_CTX_set_options_indy RAND_screen des_set_odd_parity des_set_key des_ecb_encrypt SSL_set_ex_data SSL_get_ex_data CRYPTO_num_locks CRYPTO_set_locking_callback CRYPTO_set_id_callback

Version 098l IndyBackport (SetCipher failed)
This requires me to change my IdSSLOpenSSLHeaders.pas for the one supplied in teh zip file the WhichFailedToLoad() just says nothing